# Automate textual input to a command from a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

My question is quite similar to another one [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42554/automating-textual-input-from-a-bash-script-without-using-eof) but not quite the same. I have a sequence of commands to create an ssl key/crt ect. And I want to be able to create an automated, default one. These are the commands (they came from [this page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-ubuntu-12-04)):

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 2048
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
cp server.key server.key.org
openssl rsa -in server.key.org -out server.key
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
```

If each one only took one argument then it would be fine and I would do something like

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 2048 <<< arg1
```

But one of them needs as many as 10 inputs which it asks for sequentially.

I tried something like this but it didn't work

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 2048 << foo
arg1
arg2
foo
```

EDIT: This approach is actually working I think but not for the arguments that are supposed to be passwords. Does anyone have a workaround for that?

Could it make a difference that some of the arguments are passwords?

What is the simplest way to go about this?

Comment: OpenSSL may have a way to automate this, including passwords. `man openssl` or [go to their website](https://www.openssl.org/) and read the documentation for more info.  Otherwise, this looks like a job for `expect`.  Read up on that tool as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as expected...I've been piping heredocs to openssl to create certs for years (e.g. i wrote the script below sometime in 2002, and that's the "new" version of the script...no idea when i first wrote it).

You need to provide **ALL** of the inputs that openssl expects, in the exact order that it expects them, even if some of those inputs are just a blank line (to accept the default).

For example, here's (a slightly edited version of) my script to generate self-signed certs for postfix:

```sh
#! /bin/sh

umask 077

# $site is used for the subdir to hold the certs AND for
# the certificate's Common Name
site="$1"
mkdir -p $site

umask 277

REQ="$site/key.pem"
CERT="$site/cert.pem"
SERV="$site/server.pem"
FING="$site/cert.fingerprint"

# certificate details for herenow script (configurable)
COUNTRY="AU"                # 2 letter country-code
STATE="Victoria"            # state or province name
LOCALITY="Melbourne"        # Locality Name (e.g. city)
ORGNAME="organisation name" # Organization Name (eg, company)
ORGUNIT=""                  # Organizational Unit Name (eg. section)
EMAIL="root@example.com"    # certificate's email address
# optional extra details
CHALLENGE=""                # challenge password
COMPANY=""                  # company name

DAYS="-days 365"

# create the certificate request
cat <<__EOF__ | openssl req -new $DAYS -nodes -keyout $REQ -out $REQ
$COUNTRY
$STATE
$LOCALITY
$ORGNAME
$ORGUNIT
$site
$EMAIL
$CHALLENGE
$COMPANY
__EOF__

# sign it - will ask for demoCA's password
openssl ca $DAYS -policy policy_anything -out $CERT -infiles $REQ

# cert has to be readable by postfix
chmod 644 $CERT

# create server.pem for smtpd by concatenating the certificate (cert.pem) +
# demoCA's public certificate + the host's private key (key.pem)
cat $CERT ./demoCA/cacert.pem $REQ >$SERV

# create fingerprint file
openssl x509 -fingerprint -in $CERT -noout > $FING
```

NOTE: there is no error-checking here, just assumptions about the exact order of input required by openssl for this particular task.  If you want error checking, use `expect` or perl's `Expect.pm` or python's `pexpect`.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. The only trouble I have left is when one of them requires a password, it still wants me to type it. It is accepting all other inputs fine. For example I have `cat << __EOF__ | openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr` followed by my password and then 9 blank lines and finally an __EOF__. It requires me to input the password manually and then continues to take values from the heredoc...

Comment: See `man openssl` and search for "PASS PHRASE ARGUMENTS" near the end of the document.  There are multiple ways of providing pass-phrases to openssl.

Comment: Yes I've been looking at that. The `-passin` and `-passout` flags seem to work for every command except the `openssl genrsa` command.

Is there anything special that a bash script can do to only accept keyboard input? More for future reference than for this problem.